# Adobe Air Security Aspect

Tags: air, adobe

Just created an application in Adobe Air.
Customer now says he wants security on the DVD (stop DVD from being copied or serial key)

Is there any way that I can provide some form of Serial Key Protection in Adobe AIR.
I was thinking something like writing a small script with say 50 or so 'serial numbers' in some for of xml or database.
When the script is run it allows for the execution of the program if correct serial number is given else aborts proces.

Urgent request, if someone can provide an answer there is a few £'s in it for them.

Comment: Do your serials need to be protected from multiple usage? This can be done with network activation (and will require server side.) Or you need only the simplest (cheapest) lock?

Comment: @alxx Thanks for the Reply - Basically what I need is the following: I have app on 4 sets of 2 DVD's (seperate modules). What I would like is to generate serial codes so that DVD can only run with that serial number. No online activation or server activation. Serial number is entered upon installation and if ok install proceeds, if not install aborts. Something to make the DVD hard to copy for 'joe public' would be good as added security, but first thing is a must. Ability to generate random serial keys as well. Can youm please reply and advise tomorrow? Thanks...

Comment: @alxx - Do your serials need to be protected from multiple usage? This would be useful. Say if a rogue purchased a copy with a serial number and then sold on multiple copies then this multiple usage option would be excellent. As mentioned will not be online activation of any sort. Recap stopping DVD from being copied is best. Failing this serial key usage. Stopping same serial key being used on many occasions. Hope that made sense, just need to wrap up solution. Thanks again....

Comment: Without server side, copies can be installed with same serial infinitely. There's simple no way for the copy to know if it is already installed somewhere in the world - unless server tells it.

Comment: @alxx True. But can you offer a method where you can at least offer basic serial number security; that would be a starting point. MAybe we can add server tech later on.....So could we put in a database / xml of serial numbers and on istallation if one matched the given serial number then install else abort....Please offer any advice possible....And can this be done is a script within Adobe Air.....PLEASE HELP ASAP; A REPSONE TODAY WOULD BE FANTASTIC. btw where in the world are you, I am in UK...

Answer (score 0):

I would encode some info into serials for application to test validness (some kind of checksum.) This requires several tasks:

- **Encode bytes into readable symbols of serial numbers**. Using limited alphabet of 10 digits and 22 latin chars, we get 32 variants per symbol giving 5 bit. So, 20 symbols are worth 100 bits, that's 16 bytes and a half. The hard part is to slice original 17 bytes into 5-bit chunks (nothing really hard, really, can be solved with shifts and masks, just requires careful coding.)
- **Decode symbols of serial into original bytes.** Using our custom alphabet tables, convert each symbol into 5 bit and glue them together in 17 bytes (again shifts, masks and careful coding :)
- Define serial number contents. While possibilities are countless, it can be done simple: first few bytes are 'magic' fixed ones. If application decodes them from serial, it is valid. The rest bytes are randomly varying from serial to serial.
- If we leave it this way, all our valid serials will start from the same symbols - encoded 'magic' bytes. To mix things up, I suggest using symmetrical encryption. There is library [as3 crypto](http://code.google.com/p/as3crypto/) which provides RC4 algorithm. You can test it on [demo page](http://crypto.hurlant.com/demo/) - choose 'Secret key' section, set encryption to RC4, and formats of key, text and cipher text to 'hex'.
- Now generation of serial looks like this: take 'magic' bytes, add random ones to get 16 bytes total. Encrypt this message and convert into serial.
- Program will check serial so: convert symbols into 16 bytes, decrypt them with same key, and check for 'magic' bytes to be present.

If you leave four bytes for 'magic' ones, this means one valid serial to 4 billions. For common folks, this should be enough of protection (uncommon ones will just decompile your program and shortcut the checks, so look into software like SecureSWF to prevent that.)

Comment: Thanks for this. I am giving this a go. I will contact you if anything else is needed. If successful I will ask you for contact details.....Thanks for the help up till now. Much appreciated.

Comment: by the way have you done this yourslef and do you have a little sample code that may ease things as deadline for release of software is fast approaching. Really up against it and me and the other developer will need to do, test, try....etc but if we can get some help this would be great or can you refer us to somewhere where their maybe coding samples that can assist; sorry for asking.....but tricky situation....

Comment: Is it definately possible as I would like to avoid going down the wrong path.....If you could look for it that would be much appreciated; actually a real life saver due to time scale.....

Comment: found a way round with some third party software which did the trick. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @alxx.. Hi

Can you please help as your has been the best suggestion.
Need Serial numbers and will be offline. 
I know you said that he info was in archives somewhere but can you please try and help.
Need urgently

Could you do this, 
Use a shell script to store some serial numbers and then do a check against the serial numbers and if OK then execute the main program if not enter the message "invalid serial number".
I am not a programmer but this cant be too difficult to do.
I dont mind just utilising a couple of hundred serial number which we could manually enter.

Please try and help....

Comment: If you need to embed some serials as string into program, there's no need for shell scripts - just make an array of initialized strings with serials. And you need a programmer to do it, because I don't have time to implement and debug protection system here from scratch... only to give a direction.